# Building and signing apk with TFS

Tags: tfs, xamarin.android, tfsbuild

I am trying to build my Xamarin Forms Android application with MSBuild in Team Foundation Services. I have followed all of the available procedures but it isn't working even though when I build and sign my application with Visual Studio then when I download and install my apk it works perfectly but when I try and do it with MSBuild on TFS then it goes through my entire build procedure without any problems but after I download the file and want to install it, it gives me a "Parse error - There was a problem while parsing the package" error. I followed this procedure when I setup my build procedure https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/mobile/xamarin but it doesn't want to work.

Any assistance or tips would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean you just can't installed your app after the building? Did you get any error when you build your app with vNext build on the TFS build server?

Comment: The build does not give any errors and completes successfully. It is only when I want to install the application through the apk on the phone when it gives me the error.

Comment: Got the same error. However, after check the "Unkonwn Source" and uncheck "Verify apps" on my android device. The error go away. Did you double check the security settings on your android device?